# 18 hours Cron Issue

Tags: time, cron

I am confused about cron jobs. How do I set Cron in 18 hours and 1 min also when I was tried myself like this on schedule task

[image]

The result is Cron hit my URL continuously in between these timings 06:00 to 06:59 like this

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in cron there are columns to use.

to run a task at 18:01 every day use this:

(minute) (hour) (day) (month) (day of week)

```
1 18 * * * command
```

if you want to run the same command in different time as well, I would suggest adding it again as a new entry.

The `*` applies to all, that's why it was running every minute

Comment: Thanx for sharing your experience also see my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the job every 18 hour, use `*/18` in hour fields. Also dont forget to set which minute to run that cron job in that hour.

Comment: Thanx for sharing your experience also see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanx for sharing your experience @dhchen and @Istvan

I found my answer with the help of your guidance

See the screenshot for verification

[image]

Comment: I am not sure about the `*/1` for minute. It should be just `1` instead... ?

Comment: @SteffenHeil Thanx for sharing your experience